# Use Keyring at a custom component

Tags: polkadot-js, apps

I'm trying to add a custom component to a fork of polkadot apps:
https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps

The component looks like:

```
import type { KeyringPair } from '@polkadot/keyring/types';
import { keyring } from '@polkadot/ui-keyring';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function GetSLON(): React.ReactElement {
  const [currentPair, setCurrentPair] = useState<KeyringPair | null>(() => keyring.getPairs()[0] || null);
 
  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
}

export default GetSLON;
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Keyring should be initialised via 'loadAll' before use
    at get keyring [as keyring] (bundle.js_+_11_modules:352:15)
    at Keyring.getPairs (bundle.js_+_11_modules:366:21)
    at eval (index.tsx_+_72_modules:2566:83)
    at mountState (react-dom.development.js:16986:20)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:17699:16)
    at useState (react.development.js:1623:21)
    at GetSLON (index.tsx_+_72_modules:2566:61)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20069:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21582:16)
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi @denis-reshetov, you can check how to initialize the module here https://polkadot.js.org/docs/ui-keyring/start/init. Thx!

Comment: @pepoviola thank you for prompt reply, unfortunately keyring is already initialized as the component is used within polkadot.js apps. I tried to reinitialized it as you suggested but it throws an error, that it can't be initialized twice.

Comment: How are you initializating it?

Comment: I use a keyring from polkadot.js - it's already initialized there